# Finding elements of cartesian product satisfying a set of constraints in GAP

Tags: sequences-and-series, gap, constraint-programming

Given a fixed positive integer $n \geq 3$, I want to generate a list of lists in gap with the following properties:
each list has $n$ entries $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$. We have:

- $\min(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})=a_0 \geq2$
- $a_0 \leq n+1$
- $a_{n-1}=a_0+1$ and 
  $a_i -1 \leq a_{i+1}$ for $i=0,\ldots,n-2$.
  What is the easiest way to do this in gap?

edit: I modified the above conditions a little because its enough to look at a little smaller class of such lists.(in fact $a_0 \leq n+1$ implies that the maximum of all $a_i$ has a good bound)

here is an example for n=6 :

```
L:=Cartesian([2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[3,4,5,6,7,8]);

LL:=Filtered(L, x->Minimum(x)>=2 and 
                x[6]=x[1]+1 and 
                Minimum(x)=x[1] and 
                x[2]-1 <=x[3] and 
                x[3]-1<=x[4] and 
                x[4]-1<=x[5] and 
                x[5]-1<=x[6]);
```

Using Cartesian, gap in combination with my computer isn't able to do this even for n=8.

By the way the motivation behind this is that those lists parametrise nonselfinjective Nakayama algebras with certain Kupisch series of theoretical interest.
here is the number of such lists: https://oeis.org/A007946

it doesn't grow that much, so how can i avoid generating large lists and then have to filter?

Comment: sorry to the editor, but i think something went wrong in the last two condiitons when you edited it. But thanks for giving the post a nicer look now!

Comment: An easy way would be to use L:=Cartesian([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); and then filter by  the above conditions but then one gets easily in the region of "``Error, exceeded the permitted memory". and its also not very fast this way.

Comment: something very strange happens when i type in Cartesian([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);  at first i get the exceeded permitted memory error. but when i type return; then after a while gap closes itself. is that a bug or what is happening?

Comment: Use [IteratorOfCartesianProduct](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap21.html#X7E76F5A782184823) - it will save memory, but of course for large products it may be a very long time to iterate over them. For the use of iterators, see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap30.html#X85A3F00985453F95)

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you have an idea why gap terminated when i tried to calculate Cartesian([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,‌​8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9‌​,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10‌​,11,12,13,14,15,16],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]); ?

Comment: @Mare  GAP warns you that it will require lots of memory. The `return;` supersedes this, but then GAP tries to allocate more memory than your operating system permits and it crashes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. thats too bad. so i guess there should be a better way to get those lists without looking at all cartesian products and filter afterwards

Comment: @Mare: yes, look at iterators - they are intended exactly for that reasons

Comment: ok, thanks. ill eat now and will read how to use those iterators later.

Comment: The large cartesian product from the comments contains 729000000 elements - that's A LOT. Even enumerating them with iterators will take a while, so one should exploit given constraints more efficiently, like @ahulpke does in his answer, either with GAP or using some specialised constraint solver. BTW, are you interested in counting how many of tuples will satisfy the condition or you want to calculate all of them?

Comment: The link to OEIS search returns one sequence https://oeis.org/A007946 - it would be better to edit the question to link directly to that sequence.

Comment: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/226941/number-of-nakayama-algebras-with-finite-global-dimension for reasons why im interested in those lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to build all sequences and then only select the ones which satisfy your condition you produce a lot of waste and then need to look through all of it. It will be much more effective to build the sequences entry by entry while satisfying your condition.
Observe that the $a_0+1=a_{n-1}$ condition gives you the last entry, so one only needs to build of length $n-1$ and then check the condition that $a_{n-2}<=a_0+2$, finally adding the required last entry.

The condition on the last entry, together with the fact that the sequence cannot descend by more than $1$ in each step also means that $a_i\le a_0+n-i$ which substantially reduces on intermediate lists to be thrown away.

Since lists in GAP start indexing at 0 there is a trivial index shift.

The easiest way is clearly having someone else write the code. Thus, since its Christmas, here is a function that does so:

***New version of code based on changed conditions ***

```
BuildSequences:=function(n)
local all,range,len,new,seq,i,sel;
  all:=[[]]; # start with empty
  range:=[2..2*n-1]; # valid entries
  for len in [1..n-1] do # build sequences in increasing length
    new:=[];
    for seq in all do
      # extend with all possible values based on condition
      if len=1 then
        sel:=[2..n+1]; # otherwise last entry is too large
      else
        sel:=Filtered(range,x->x>=seq[len-1]-1 and x>=seq[1]
               and x<=seq[1]+n-len+1);
      fi;
      for i in sel do
        Add(new,Concatenation(seq,[i]));
      od;
    od;
    all:=new;
  od;
  # Can we add the last entry while remaining valid?
  all:=List(all,x->Concatenation(x,[x[1]+1]));
  return all;
end;
```

It produces some overhead but far less than trying all sequences would do so. It produces counts 8, 35, 139, 539, 2078, 8007, 30887, 119339, 461889 that are consistent (difference 1) with the linked OEIS entry.

Comment: Thanks, this is by far my best christmas present ;)

Comment: @Mare You're welcome. I'm still somewhat puzzled by your modified conditions. Do you really want $a_0\le n+1$ only for index 1?

Comment: yes, this will imply that in fact all other entries are smaller than 2n.

Comment: is there some trick to stop gap from terminating ? like giving gap more memory or something. i hoped to get results at least for n=10 and my pc isnt able to do it at the moment.

Comment: @Mare I have slightly replaced the code to use the new conditions and be better with memory. Now it should do 11 easily.

Comment: @Mare  Concerning memory use you might want to read  http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#6.2

Comment: thanks, sadly my computer dies (for n=8) when i filter that list again, now using some homological algebra things.

Comment: i just noted that you said "difference 1". thats strange, since i always get 1 more than you by using the Cartesian and then filter.

Comment: I think it has to be "range:=[2..2*n];" instead of "range:=[2..2*n-1];" to be correct. then also the sequence doesnt differ by 1 anymore of the OEIS sequence.

Comment: @Mare  Yes, I think yore right and this is a mistake in my version.

Answer (score 1):

I will post another answer just to illustrate the use of **iterators of cartesian products** in case they may be useful for the readers of this question (but of course, this approach does not lead you that far in this particular problem as the code provided in @ahulpke's answer).

Starting from your example for $n=6$, the call to `Cartesian` creates a huge overhead since first GAP actually generates a list of 527076 tuples, and then filters them to pick only 540 ones satisfying the constraints:

```
gap> L:=Cartesian([2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[3,4,5,6,7,8]);;
gap> Size(L);
527076
gap> LL:=Filtered(L, x->Minimum(x)>=2 and 
>                 x[6]=x[1]+1 and 
>                 Minimum(x)=x[1] and 
>                 x[2]-1 <=x[3] and 
>                 x[3]-1<=x[4] and 
>                 x[4]-1<=x[5] and 
>                 x[5]-1<=x[6]);;
gap> Length(LL);
540
```

This is how to do the same using [iterator](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap30.html#X85A3F00985453F95), enumerating tuples one by one instead of generating the whole list at once:

```
gap> L:=IteratorOfCartesianProduct([2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[3,4,5,6,7,8]);
<iterator>
gap> LL:=[];
[  ]
gap> for x in L do
> if Minimum(x)>=2 and 
>   x[6]=x[1]+1 and 
>   Minimum(x)=x[1] and 
>   x[2]-1 <=x[3] and 
>   x[3]-1<=x[4] and 
>   x[4]-1<=x[5] and 
>   x[5]-1<=x[6] then
>     Add(LL,x);
>   fi;
> od;
gap> Length(LL);
540
```

Iterators provide a possibility to loop over the elements of a (countable) collection or list, without repetition, and this is exactly the case for `IteratorOfCartesianProduct`. For many collections, an iterator over them need not store all their elements (it's even possible to construct an iterator of some infinite domains, such as the field of rational numbers).