# Finding lists as fast as possible via GAP

Tags: gap, constraint-programming

Call a list with $n$ entries $[c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}]$ an n-LNakayama algebra in case the following conditions are satisfied:

- $c_i \geq 2$ are natural numbers for $i \neq n-1$ and $c_{n-1}=1$.
- $c_i -1 \leq c_{i+1}$ for all $i=0,1,...,n-2$.

I managed to program this, imitating the programme of ahulpke here: [Finding elements of cartesian product satisfying a set of constraints in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587593/finding-elements-of-cartesian-product-satisfying-a-set-of-constraints-in-gap) .

Here the program:

```
BuildSequencesLNak:=function(n)
local all,range,len,new,seq,i,sel;
all:=[[1]];
range:=[2..n];
for len in [1..n-1] do
    new:=[];
    for seq in all do
        sel:=Filtered(range, x->x<=1+seq[1]);
        for i in sel do
            Add(new,Concatenation([i],seq));
        od;
    od;
    all:=new;
od;
return all;
end;
```

Call an index $i$ projective-injective in case $c_i \geq c_{i-1}$ (setting $c_{-1}=1$ and calculating mod $n$ for the indices).

Now call a $n$-LNakayama algebra special in case the following is true:

In case $i$ is projective-injective, also $i+r$ is projective injective for every $r=c_{i-1},c_{i-1}+1,...,c_i -1$ (no condition for this $i$ in case $c_{i-1}=c_i -1$).

I can program also this by using `Filtered` in GAP after making the list of all n-LNakayama algebras with the above program `BuildSequencesLNak`, but it is not as fast as I want and so I wonder how to make it faster.

I can get the list for about n=16 and then it loads very long. I would hope that with a somehow better program one might get to n=21 or 22 to test some conjectures.

Example:
All 5-LNakayama algebras:
[ [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 ],
  [ 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ] ]

The special ones among them:

[ [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 3, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 ] ]

The number of n-LNakayama algebras should be $C_{n-1}$, the Catalan numbers.
The number of special n-LNakayama algebras should be given by https://oeis.org/A005043 (at least for $n \leq 15$), although I know no proof.

Comment: I've edited the code to show how to display it better by indenting it by 4 spaces. Also, I find the terminology a bit confusing: I'd expect some character between `L` and `Nakayama`, and also don't call a lists of lists an algebra. Finally, it may be interesting to post numbers of such objects for $n$ up to 16 as you've already computed them - to show the scale of the problem and for testing alternative approaches, if any.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by -$c_i \geq 2$? I suppose the minus is there for the bulleted list, then insert a space after minus to display it properly.

Comment: I edited it. And those lists uniquely determine certain Nakayama algebras with special properties.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious speed improvements are to replace `sel` with an immediate bound calculation and to build the list in reverse order, avoiding `Concatenation` and a list of length 1, that is the inner loop becomes

```
    for i in [2..seq[Length(seq)]+1] do
      nl:=ShallowCopy(seq);
      Add(nl,i);
      Add(new,nl);
    od;
```

However a back-of-an envelope calculation indicates that for $n=21$ memory use might be prohibitive. You might have to think about reducing intermediate storage and discarding sequences that are not special.

Comment: I am thinking whether GAP is the right tool for this. We had a similar situation in https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL18/Kitaev/kitaev10.html where we started with GAP, found some optimisations, saved previous results to avoid recalculating them for the next level, but at the end used the [Minion](https://constraintmodelling.org/minion/) constraint solver instead.

Comment: If you really just care about the special sequences, the next step would be to have the construction process abort a branch, as soon as only non-special will be created. I haven't thought about how to do this in this example.